# Cannot create K8S cluster in Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When I try to create a K8S cluster in GKE below error is occurred. Need some help to go through.

[Failed to create the K8S cluster in GKE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1DUi.png)

1. I was trying with different zones but same issue is occurred.

Comment: Will look into this.  Feel free to ping me on chat.

Comment: In the short term, you might want to try a different region (e.g. us-east)